# For any integer $n>0$, does there always exist a prime $p>n$ such that $p\mid 2^n-1$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

For any integer $n>0$, does there always exist a prime $p>n$ such that $p\mid 2^n-1$?
It's easy to verify this result for $1<n<100$ by computer.
But for any integer $n>0$, is it always true?

Comment: See also [AMM problem 12043](http://doi.org/10.1080/00029890.2018.1447207).

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev Thank you! And if >6, can >+1?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes. By [Zsigmondy's theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zsigmondy%27s_theorem) for $n>6$ there exists a prime divisor $p$ of $2^n-1$ which does not divide $2^k-1$ for $k<n$. For such $p$, $n$ is a multiplicative order of 2 modulo $p$, thus it divides $p-1$, and $p>n$.

Comment: Zsigmondy's theorem as you stated it doesn't hold if $n = 6$ (although the desired result is still true then).

Comment: @JeremyRouse thank you, fixed this

Comment: By the way, as the linked article mentions, the $(a,b)=(2,1)$ case of Zsigmondy goes back to Bang.

Comment: @FedorPetrov Thank you! And if $n>6$, can $p>n+1$?

Comment: @FedorPetrov I have got it! The largest prime factor of $2^n-1$ is greater than or equal to $2n+1$. You can find it in my next question! Than you again!