# For any integer $n>6$, does there always exist a prime $p>n+1$ such that $p\mid 2^n-1$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

For any integer $n>6$, does there always exist a prime $p>n+1$ such that $p\mid 2^n-1$?
It's true for $6<n<100$. But for $n>100$?

Comment: How does this differ from your earlier question, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/454148/for-any-integer-n0-does-there-always-exist-a-prime-pn-such-that-p-mid-2

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sometimes $p$ may be equal to $n+1$ and I want to exclude this case.

Comment: Largest prime factor of $2^{12}-1$ is $13$. Largest prime factor of $2^n-1$ is tabulated, with references, at https://oeis.org/A005420

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes (except for $n=12$, as noted by Gerry Myerson). This is due to A. Schinzel, in strong form, see "On primitive prime factors of $a^n−b^n$" (Proc. Camb. Philos. Soc. 58, 555-562 (1962)).

Let $P(n)$ be the largest prime factor of $n$.
The inequality $P(2^n-1) \ge n+1$ ($n>1$) goes back to Bang. Bang proved that if $n \neq 1,6$ there is a prime $p \mid 2^n-1$ (now called Zsigmondy prime) that does not divide $2^d-1$ for $d<n$. Since any prime $p \le n$ divides one of $\{2^d-1\}_{d=0}^{n-1}$, this shows a Zsigmondy prime satisfies $p\ge n+1$ and so $P(2^n-1)\ge n+1$ follows (and happens to be true for $n=6$ as well, despite no Zsigmondy prime in this case).

Schinzel, in the above paper, shows $P(2^n-1)\ge 2n+1$ if $n \not\in \{1,2,4,6,12\}$. The proof still uses ideas of Bang and Zsigmondy. This answers your question positively, except in the case $n=12$ for which $P(2^{12}-1)=13$.

Let me also mention that Feit showed that there is a Zsigmondy prime factor of $2^n-1$ which satisfies either $p>n+1$ or $p^2 \mid 2^n-1$ (if $n \not\in \{1,2,4,6,10,12,18\}$), see "On large Zsigmondy primes" (Proc. Am. Math. Soc. 102, No. 1, 29-36 (1988)).

Erdős conjectured that $P(2^n-1)/n \to \infty$, and after several results proving this conditionally, C. L. Stewart gave an unconditional proof (his paper also gives a great survey), see "On divisors of Lucas and Lehmer numbers" (Acta Math. 211, No. 2, 291-314 (2013)).

Comment: Thorough as always. $+1$